# Skip to a specific Step based on Radio button Check

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a multi-step Form Wizard (Bootstrap 3.3.7), all is working fine, but I tried to set it up where on Step #2 at the Bottom of the page Radio Buttons: (Rent, Own, Unsheltered). when I click on say Own, it should then skip Renter Step and take me directly to OWNER Step and same for Unsheltered.
I tried without any luck. right now with this javascript it does go to a desired step displaying it at the bottom not as a Real Step like what I get when I click next.
Any Help will certainly be much appreciated .
    Here is my JSFiddle code:
    enter code here
    https://jsfiddle.net/alachgar/43wgLvxr/2/

```
<script>
    $(document).on("click",".step-3",function(){
        current_step = $(this).closest("fieldset");
        next_step = $("#step-3");
        next_step.show();
        current_step.hide();
        //setProgressBar(--current);
      });
    $(document).on("click",".step-4",function(){
        current_step = $(this).closest("fieldset");
        next_step = $("#step-4");
        next_step.show();
        current_step.hide();
        //setProgressBar(--current);
      });
    $(document).on("click",".step-5",function(){
        current_step = $(this).closest("fieldset");
        next_step = $("#step-5");
        next_step.show();
        current_step.hide();
        //setProgressBar(--current);
      });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your linked code in the javascript look at line 101:

```
 if (isValid) nextStepWizard.removeAttr('disabled').trigger('click');
```

you go in a sequential manner, so no matter what I choose it just enables the next step.
There should be something like (pseudo code):

```
   if (isValid && nextStep=="rent") nextStep("rent").removeAttr('disabled').trigger('click');
   if (isValid && nextStep=="owner") nextStep("owner").removeAttr('disabled').trigger('click');
```

and so on - so you probably have to redesign this functionality

```
nextStepWizard = $('div.setup-panel div a[href="#' + curStepBtn + '"]').parent().next().children("a"),
```

so to create a function which will also allow correct backward movement (if suitable)

Comment: Thank you for your prompt help.. any adea how to redesign that.. I am not very well versed in JS...
Much appreciate it .
Ed-

Comment: Alright, 
I got it to where it's going to the right Step, I do need to make sure it's submitted from there, I think I just need to add Submit Buttons in each Final Step (Renter, Owner, Unsheltered...) so it doesn't go to the wrong Step as it doesn't need to.
I also wantedt to disable unnecessary Step Green Sqaures at the Progress bar..
Check it out at my JSfiddle  .

Comment: You should just  make three steps, the last one starting as step 3 and when chosen renaming to rent/owner/... so all on all "last" steps the button should be submit and leaving/restarting empty the page or whatever you need to .do

Comment: I finally just modified my JS code accordignly..
             <script language="javascript">
  //Goto Specific Step Onclick
   $(document).on("click",".step-3",function(){
    curStep = $(this).closest(".setup-content"),
    //current_step = curStep.attr("id"),
    next_step = $("#step-3");
    next_step.show();
    curStep.hide();
    //setProgressBar(--current);
     }); 
   //etc..
  </script>

Comment: Thank you Sir. Much appreciated !